# How to test if condition using jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am new to react and not able to find how can i get the code coverage done for my below mentioned function using jest.

For the sake of clarity I have created a function just similar to what I am using :

```
setName: function setName () {
  var storage = localStorage.getItem(user);
  var session = sessionStorage.getItem(temp);

  if ((session === null || session === undefined) && (storage === null && storage === undefined)) {
    var name = "window.name";

    if (name  === 'John') {
      changeName(name);
    } else if (name === 'Jane') {
      changeName(name);
    } else if (name  === 'Mark') {
      changeName(name);
    } else {
      changeName('John');
    }
  } else if (session !== null) {
    changeName(session);
  } else if (storage !== null) {
    changeName(storage);
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Please fix the code formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be able to specify the name 'John', 'Jane', etc.  To do this with your sample you will need to save the appropriate data into localStorage and sessionStorage before running the test.

In your test file:

```
localStorage.setItem('John');
sessionStorage.setItem('A Session');
// do the test now and test what you expect to get back when the user is John.

localStorage.setItem('Jane');
// do the test now and test what you expect to get back when the user is Jane.
```

The tests could be done with a loop and arrays if the results being tested for are basic and you can simply do a foreach or similar.

```
testData = [
    { Name: 'John', Result: true},
    { Name: 'Jane', Result: false}
];

testData.forEach(function(testItem) {
    expect(setName(testItem.Name)).toBe(testItem.Result);
}
```

Another option is to move the access to local and session storage out of your function setName() and then use dependency injection or other functions in your code to get these values.  Then you can set up a mock (or dummy function) for returning the data for the storage which returns hard set literal data to test each part of the if() structure.

Comment: localStorage.setItem('John');

sessionStorage.setItem('A Session');
// do the test now and test what you expect to get back when the user is John. In my code I am calling a private function when this happens I am not sure how I go about it in test

Comment: I (and others) would need to see what you are doing and trying to test to help better.  My guess is that your private function is doing something else, and you need to ensure the result happened.  This might be that a different local storage setting was populated, in which case, your test would need to validate the proper data was saved.

Comment: what private function is doing is just one line it is setting the state to this.state.name=name(it is passed in the function);. I apologize for silly questions but I am not able to even figure out how to write test case in this scenario.I am doing this it('set name to name in local storage if local storage is not null', function () {
        localStorage.setItem('name','john');
        // I am confused here as how to call the function(setName) and what to expect});

Comment: What I would do then is update the original question with your short example, and the test you are trying to do.  This way we can see the wholesome issue.  One thing that a number of people will tell you, is to test your code, not others.  Therefore, the setItem of the name into the Local storage does not really need to be tested, it will work.  However, if you want to, then you need to write your test to first empty the storage or set it to null, call your function, get value from storage, evaluate that it is correct to what you expect.